# Custom IdentifierGenerator not used in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I implemented a `CustomerInternalNumberGenerator` that implements JPA's `IdentifierGenerator` as follows:

```java
package ch.pcngroup.gestionale.generator;

import ch.pcngroup.gestionale.util.InternalNumber;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;
import org.springframework.data.convert.Jsr310Converters;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CustomerInternalNumberGeneratorimplements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) {
        String candidate = InternalNumber.generateRandomInternalNumber();
        try(Connection connection = sharedSessionContractImplementor.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection()) {
            System.out.println(candidate); // Just to check -- NEVER called!
            while (true) {
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE internal_number = ?");
                stmt.setString(1, "customer");
                stmt.setString(2, candidate);
                ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery();
                if(!set.next()) return candidate;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
    }
}
```

and I have a JPA Entity `Customer` as follows:

```java
package ch.pcngroup.gestionale.entity;

import ch.pcngroup.gestionale.generator.CustomerInternalNumberGenerator;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "customerInternalNumberGenerator", type = CustomerInternalNumberGenerator.class)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "customerInternalNumberGenerator")
    private String internalNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String street;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String postCode;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(2)", nullable = false)
    private String country;
    private String phone;
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

I'd like the `String internalNumber` of the `Customer` class to be autogenerated by the above generator.
The generator `generate()` method does not seem to be called at all: in fact, when I save a Customer to the DB via JPA (using the repository's `save()` method, the `println` statement in the `generate()` method is not called (nothing gets printed)). As a result, all added Customers have an `internalNumber` of `null`.

Why is this happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be related to the way you've set up the generation of the `internalNumber` field using the custom generator.

In the usage of the `@GeneratedValue(generator = "customerInternalNumberGenerator")` annotation on the `internalNumber` field, the `internalNumber` is a string and not an UUID, so using `@GeneratedValue` might not be the right approach.

Instead of using `@GeneratedValue`, you could manually generate the `internalNumber` in your code and set it before saving the `Customer` entity. The generator's `generate()` method might not be called because it's designed for generating identifiers for IDs, so UUID, not other fields such as a string.

you could modify your `Customer` class to achieve this:

```java
// imports

// Customer.java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true) // Ensure uniqueness of internalNumber
    private String internalNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    // ... other fields ...

    @PrePersist
    public void generateInternalNumber() {
        internalNumber = InternalNumber.generateRandomInternalNumber();
    }
}
```

By using the `@PrePersist` annotation, the `generateInternalNumber()` method will be automatically called just before the entity is persisted to the database, ensuring that the `internalNumber` field is generated and set before saving.

Here's some [good article](https://nullbeans.com/how-to-use-prepersist-and-preupdate-in-jpa-hibernate/) about the PrePersist annotation.

**EDIT:**

To ensure uniqueness before saving the `Customer` entity you can query the database to check if the generated `internalNumber` already exists before setting it. You don't need to access the repository or JPA connection directly within the entity class. Instead, you can create a service or manager class to handle this logic and then use it when saving the entity.

I could think of something like this:

1. Create a service class to generate and set the `internalNumber`:

```java
// CustomerService.java
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public Customer createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        String generatedInternalNumber;
        do {
            generatedInternalNumber = InternalNumber.generateRandomInternalNumber();
        } while (customerRepository.existsByInternalNumber(generatedInternalNumber));
        
        customer.setInternalNumber(generatedInternalNumber);
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

2. Modify your `Customer` class:

```java
// Customer.java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String internalNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    // ... other fields ...

    // No need for @PrePersist in this case
}
```

The `CustomerService` class is responsible for generating a unique `internalNumber` by checking if it already exists in the database before saving a new `Customer` entity and the `existsByInternalNumber` method in the `CustomerRepository` checks if a `Customer` with the given `internalNumber` already exists in the database.

By doing this you no longer need the `@PrePersist` method because the `internalNumber` is set in the service before saving the entity.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Hi @Francesco, thanks! This kind of work, but if the `InternalNumber.generateInternalNumber()` happens to generate an already used number, Hibernate will correctly throw a `ConstraintViolationException`. How can I query the DB to check if the number was already used? In the `@PrePersist` method I don't have access to the repository, nor to a JPA `Connection` object. Thank you and sorry for re-asking, but I'm a beginner with JPA

Comment: @Admin_PCNGroup edited the post, hopefully i got it right!

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Thank you for your time and effort!